# How to get the multipart/form-data from a request in a serviceworker for chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, service-worker

I see in the API that there is [`req.formData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/formData) however this isn't currently supported in chrome.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {

    var req = event.request;
    if(req.method == "POST"){

        //Not available in chrome
        req.formData().then(function(formData){
             //Do stuff to form data here
        }).catch(function(err) {});
    }
}
```

I was wondering what the next best approach for getting the form data in my `serviceworker` for chrome.

Comment: Your could try taking an existing node-specific library, like [`busboy`](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy), running it through [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), and then seeing if the resulting code works as expected in the service worker context. You'd need to wrap the event-based interface with a Promise so that you had something that would work when passed to `FetchEvent.respondWith()`.